# How to identify which certifications are beneficial to my career?

Tags: career-development, certification

I have 4 years of experience in my field. I am thinking about getting a certification, but I don't know what will help me to improve my career opportunities in the near future.

How can I determine which certifications are available in my field and which will be the most beneficial?

Comment: "Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or "what skills should I learn?"). Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do."

Comment: I reworded the question to be more on topic with our standards at the Workplace, since I don't think I've seen this asked before. For future reference, be sure to check our our [Help Center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) for tips on what is [on-topic](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Very similar question - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/how-can-i-evaluate-if-an-optional-certificate-will-help-my-career-or-not?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

A large part of this depends on your locale, and the domain in which you want to work.

In many parts of the world Certifications are rather important, but in my experience, in my field, far less so in the U.S.

One way to approach this is to search job boards and see what kinds of certifications they are currently requiring in your locale, for the kinds of jobs you are seeking.

When I tried that a few years back, I learned that generally speaking, US employers seeking Software Testers don't require certifications very much (if at all): http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/software-qa-certifications-aid-to.html