# Quitting job to get data analyst nanodegree

Tags: quitting, learning

I'm working as a software engineer and now I'm planning to quit my job to take up the Data Analyst Nanodegree course: https://in.udacity.com/course/data-analyst-nanodegree--nd002/ The plan is to finish up the course in 2 months and then start applying for data scientist jobs. I'm contemplating on quitting because I lack self discipline in pursuing an online course for 9 months.

What do you think? Is it advisable to quit a high paying job which demands a lot of time and pursue full time learning? How likely it is that I'll finish up the course contents in 2 months learning full time and then get hired as an entry level data scientist?

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you'd have better self-discipline when doing it full-time? If you're working a 40 hour week, that still leaves a massive amount of time to spend on such a course - if you're unable to find time, you should probably review your priorities and motivations.

Comment: I think you might also find useful this question on the value of "nanodegrees": [Are MOOC certifications a viable replacement for college education requirements?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71685/are-mooc-certifications-a-viable-replacement-for-college-education-requirements)

Comment: If I were you, I would look for job ads for data scientists and see if they accept nanodegrees as qualifying. You could even check with the data scientists at some of those companies to see if they would be willing to look at you with your experience once you get the nanodegree .I would do this before I quit my current job.

Answer (score 10):

> What do you think?

I think it's a terrible plan.

> Is it advisable to quit a high paying job which demands a lot of time
>   and pursue full time learning?

In my opinion, it would be completely foolish - particularly when the course is specifically designed to be taken in your spare time.

> How likely it is that I'll finish up the course contents in 2 months
>   learning full time and then get hired as an entry level data
>   scientist?

There's no way to know. You may or may not finish it in 2 months. And you may or may not get hired as an entry level data scientist based on completion of a single "nanodegree" course.

What I do know is that you would have the same chance of being hired if you spent the recommended 10 hours per week for 9 months on the program, in your spare time.

And you could seek the job while you are still on a payroll.

And you wouldn't have to explain to a potential employer why you felt it was necessary to quit a good job for this ("because I don't have enough self-discipline"?) and why you wouldn't quit the job they are offering.

And if it took a while to find the data scientist job, you would still be earning good money.

> I'm contemplating on quitting because I lack self discipline in
>   pursuing an online course for 9 months.

If you don't have the self-discipline, then take the course nights and weekends and get it done in 3 months. You would have a far more compelling story to tell potential employers that way.