# Linkedin: Should I include my certificate?

Tags: linkedin

I am currently a university student (business administration) and trying to improve my Linkedin page. I remembered that when I was a freshman in high school, I went to Camp Kennedy Space Center and completed a 3-Days Robotics program. I also received a signed certificate.

My question is that since this is not actually relevant to my major, should I include it or not? If yes, which heading should I include it under as it is a participation certificate and nothing more? 
Thank you!

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't include it.

Comment: What year of university?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I evaluate if an optional certificate will help my career or not?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/how-can-i-evaluate-if-an-optional-certificate-will-help-my-career-or-not)

Comment: Why do you believe it’s relevant to your career? What advantage would this give you?

Comment: Was this event something serious? Or more like fun for chidlren?

Answer (score 2):

Since LinkedIn is a summary record of your career, education, professional experiences and accomplishments, you can certainly include your Camp Kennedy experience as part of your high school experience (in free text under your High School details).

We are all on a self-exploration journey with various interests at different points in our lives. The addition will give your future employer a view into your authentic personality and interests. All the best as you embark on your career journey!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, My point of view as a recruiter you have to consider your Linkedin profile the same as your resume. Because recruiters will review your profile and there is a certificate section on LinkedIn if you didn't write something in it that's mean you don't have and you will lose the job opportunity.